# angular ui-router $state.reload() unable to update scope variable after file upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm uploading a file with [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) and I'm trying to

1. reload the state and all resolves when the upload is complete
2. Then update a scope variable to show a message on the template

Here's my code

```
$scope.upload.success = false

$scope.uploader = new FileUploader(
    headers: headers    
    url: url
    )

$scope.uploadFile = ->
    queue = $scope.uploader.queue
    last_item = queue[queue.length-1]
    if last_item != undefined
      $timeout(->
        last_item.upload()
      , 3000)
    else
      $scope.nofile = true
      Flash.create('warning', 'Please select an excel file to upload')

$scope.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) ->
    Flash.create('success', response.message)
    ################
    $state.reload()
    $scope.upload.success = true
    ################
```

Running console.log($scope.upload.success) after $state.reload() returns true, but $scope.upload.success on the view remains false. How do I change the scope on the view?

Answer (score -1):

Basicly this has to do with Angular being unaware of changes happening inside the onSuccessItem.

One solution would be to wrap the neccesary code in the $apply method:

```
$scope.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) ->
    Flash.create('success', response.message)
    ################
    $state.reload()
    $scope.$apply(() -> 
      $scope.upload.success = true
    )
    ################
```

Another solution would be to replace the callback and call $scope.$apply();

```
$scope.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) ->
    Flash.create('success', response.message)
    ################
    $state.reload()
    $scope.upload.success = true
    $scope.$apply()
    ################
```

Note: I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript (or whatever syntax this is).

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work but $state.reload() just resets the scope. wrapping the apply in a timeout doesn't seem to work neither.

Comment: I'm unsure why u want to reload the state tbh

Comment: It's to refresh an ng-resource cache. I left out the cache invalidation code because it's irrelevant.

Comment: So you don't want the scope to be reset ?

Comment: I want the resolves to be refreshed, hence $state.reload(). 

Then I'd like to change scope.upload.success to true and for it to remain true because I'm using it to render a partial in the view. Right now the partial  renders for a few milliseconds and resets after $state.reload()

Comment: What about https://mwop.net/blog/2014-05-08-angular-ui-router-reload.html ?

Comment: But I gotta admit I think this is expected behavior that the $scope gets reset. Unless I miss something.

Comment: Yeah I tried that link, and changing reload to $state.go, $state.transitionTo, wrapping the apply in a timeout, wrapping $state.reload() in a timeout, wrapping both in a timeout, and wrapping the apply in a promise but nothing worked for me. It's a real mystery.